# Group dates into list based on value

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

I have a json object that I'm trying to group item together in.

```
sorted_stack = sorted(stack, key=itemgetter('Date'))
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_stack, key=lambda x:x['Date']):
        print(key)
        print(list(group))
```

this code returns values grouped by date as the key and then a list of teams and dates like this

```
 2020-03-08
[{'Team': 'ORL', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'ORL', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'ORL', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'PHO', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'PHO', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'PHO', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'PHO', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'MIN', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'MIN', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}, {'Team': 'MIN', 'Date': '2020-03-08'}]
```

However, I need it to return and key value pair like this

```
2020-03-08 : [{'Team': 'ORL', 'Date': ['2020-03-08', '2020-03-08', '2020-03-08']}, {'Team': 'PHO', 'Date': ['2020-03-08','2020-03-08', '2020-03-08', '2020-03-08']}, {'Team': 'MIN', 'Date': ['2020-03-08','2020-03-08', '2020-03-08']}
```

where all the dates for a specific team are in a list as the value for the key `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted_stack, key=lambda x:x['Date']):
    print(key)
    temp = {}
    for i in group:
        temp.setdefault(i['Team'], []).append(i['Date'])
    print(temp)
    #OR
    print([{"Team": k, "Date": v} for k, v in temp.items()])
```